# Bash binary reports a different version at different times

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, shebang

I am running a bash script with the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` on RHEL 7.6 . The bash version is 4.2 and I have verified this by running `/bin/bash --version`. But once this script is being executed, the BASH_VERSION variable being reported inside the script is 3.X. I have printed out the binary location when the script is running is indeed /bin/bash by printing `$(ls -l /proc/$$/exe)`. That actually reports /bin/bash
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 xx yy 0 Jan 28 21:03 /proc/6855/exe -> /bin/bash`

I am really confused as to how this can happen?

Comment: `bash --version` doesn't report the version of your current interactive shell; it runs the `bash` found via path lookup and reports *its* version. `which bash` should report a path other than `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Likewise, what does `/bin/bash --version` print?

Comment: `type -a bash` will show you multiple results, with `/bin/bash` being not the first one, is my guess.

Comment: I am running /bin/bash --version

Comment: How are you running the script? It appears to be ignoring the shebang. `$$`, by the way, is inherited from a parent shell; it's not necessarily the process ID of the process actually executing your script.

Comment: It is being invoked from another bash script. I could use BASHPID if that helps